# Creating an alias in linux to remove mutiple files

Tags: linux, alias

So I'm new to Linux and I'm looking for a push in the right direction with this. 
I have to create a couple of new aliases in a new text file, (which I did, using pico) expect for one that has been giving me trouble. 
What I have to do is, create an alias with the name "rm" that will prompt once before removing more than three files, or when removing recursively.
Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
alias rm='rm -I'
```

Assuming that your **rm** is relatively current. This isn't really a programming question, though.
Edit: It's a question about reading man-pages (or failing to do so).

Comment: If we do like this we will lost default rm ..sorry if i am wrong

Comment: @JohnAnkanna, that is correct, and exactly what he asked for.  You are, however, free to do \rm to bypass that alias ...

Comment: oh!! very smart one  thanks for the information